# connecting php to mysql and sending inputs but getting error execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to send inputs to database but i get this error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\memebership\index.php on line 26

I'm using xampp and my sql and here is my php code :

```
$insertmbr = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO memebres(pseudo, mail, motdepasse) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
         $insertmbr->execute(array($pseudo, $mail, $mdp));
```

Comment: You are confusing PDO and MySQLi. The latter is more tedious.

Comment: can you show me how to solve this problém im new to php

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) and also the error message, `mysqli_stmt::execute()` does not accept any parameters.

You are passing a parameter, which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) function only receives an array with parameters in PDO. This is MySQLi, it's different. You would bind parameters that way:

```
$insertmbr = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO memebres(pseudo, mail, motdepasse) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$insertmbr ->bind_param($pseudo, $mail, $mdp);
$insertmbr ->execute();
```

Comment: okay i did exactly what you said and now im getting this error  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\memebership\index.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C

Comment: I did something wrong, made some changes it should work now.

Comment: im getting a warning ! mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables